# Creating image in Docker fails

Tags: image, docker, containers

I'm trying to create my own image on Docker container. I wrote my Docker file as given below:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install astyle ruby
```

But on running

```
docker build -t username/newname .
```

It gives an error Error response from daemon:

```
mkdir /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder705720973: no space left on device
```

I'm new to Docker. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have pulled a lot of images i guess. Check all your images using following command:

```
sudo docker images
```

If you see many images, try deleting some that you don't need anymore using the following command

```
sudo docker rmi <iamge_id>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Since that hasn't been made clear yet; the 'no space left on device' error means the storage of wherever the /var/lib/docker resides, is full.